# how to resolve this error 1064

Tags: mysql

```
create table reg (
    usrid varchar(10),
    pwd varchar2(10) not null,
    hque varchar(20),
    hans varchar(10),
    fname varchar2(10) not null,
    lname varchar(10) not null,
    dob date not null,
    add varchar(10) not null,
    city varchar(10) not null,
    pin number(6) not null,
    state varchar(10) not null,
    country varchar(10) not null,
    ccname varchar(10) not null,
    ccno varchar(10) not null,
    email varchar(30) not null,
    primary key(usrid)
);
```

The statement above gives me the error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varch
>   ar(10) ,pwd varchar(10) not null,
>   hque varch' at line 1

Could anyone help me find what is wrong with my statement?

Comment: Reformatted your question to be an actual readable question.

Answer (score 1):

A few things;

- In MySQL, `VARCHAR2` and `NUMBER` are not valid types. The create table seems to be copy and pasted from Oracle.
- In MySQL, `add` is not a valid column name unless quoted with backticks.